# Stream no esta escuchando cuando escaneo un codigo qr

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, plugin

Buenas esto creando un plugin para flutter nativo usando kotlin el cual su propósito es escanear códigos de barras y qr usando una librería especifica. Cree un eventchannel para poder escuchar cuando se escanea un código pero este no esta escuchando de nada.

Lam manera en que funciona mi aplicación es que tengo un initstate donde mando a llamar el método de initScanner(), ya una vez que se ha cargado el estado de la aplicación tengo un onPress el cual primero ejecuta la función openScanner() el cual esta me regresa un status 1 que de acuerdo con la librería que uso significa OPEN_SCANNER_ISDECODING. A después de que corre la funcion openScanner() mando a llamar mi stream de la siguiente manera:  **_scannerPlugin.qrCodeStream?.listen((event) => log('QR code: $event'));**, pero mi problema es que nunca entra al stream e imprime el log.

Antes de hacer el listen hago un inspect de qrCodeStream y me regresa la siguiente información:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es mi código en kotlin.

```
private var method : MethodChannel ?= null
  private var event : EventChannel ?= null
  private var mEventSink : EventChannel.EventSink ?= null

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    ScannerManager.init(flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext)
    method = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "scanner")
    event = EventChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, "scanner_stream")
    method!!.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    event!!.setStreamHandler(this)
  }

override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall,  result: Result) {
    val instance : ScannerManager = ScannerManager.getInstance()
    when (call.method) {
      "init" -> {
        scannerListener()
        result.success(instance.initScanner())
      }
      "open" -> {
        result.success(instance.OpenScanner())
      }
      else -> result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  private fun scannerListener() {
        ScannerManager.getInstance().addScannerManagerListener(object : ScannerManagerListener {
          override fun Error(errcode: Int, msg: String?) {
            val result = object {
              var status = errcode
              var msg = msg
            }
             mEventSink!!.success(result)
          }

          override fun decodeResult(statusCode: Int, msg: String?) {
            val result = object {
              var status = statusCode
              var msg = msg
            }
             mEventSink!!.success(result)
          }
        })
  }

  override fun onListen(arguments: Any?, events: EventChannel.EventSink?) {
    mEventSink = events
  }

  override fun onCancel(arguments: Any?) {
    mEventSink = null
  }
```

Ya después en la parte de código donde mando a llamar mi methodchannel y event channel

```
class MethodChannelScanner extends ScannerPlatform {
  /// The method channel used to interact with the native platform.
  @visibleForTesting
  static const methodChannel = MethodChannel('scanner');
  static const eventChannel = EventChannel('scanner_stream');

  @override
  Future<int?> initScanner() async =>
      await methodChannel.invokeMethod<int?>('init');

  @override
  Future<int?> openScanner() async =>
      await methodChannel.invokeMethod<int?>('open');

  @override
  Stream<dynamic>? get qrCodeStream {
    return eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream();
  }
}
```

El siguiente enlace lleva a la documentación de la librería que estoy usando:
https://sistemas.cruzperez.com/felipe/Hytera%20Scanner%20API%20Reference%20V00.pdf

Comment: Te recomendaría usar un plugin que ya esté hecho, a no ser que por algún motivo muy específico necesites crear uno propio.

Comment: Ocupo hacerlo porque no e encontrado ninguno que este hecho específicamente para el hytera pnc 560 y me están pidiendo que usen el scanner que tiene y no la camara